# Multiple controller route patterns with asp.net core 3 UseEndpoints

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm converting an Asp.Net Core 2.2 Mvc application to 3.0; when I try to refactor the code to use UseEndpoints instead of UseMvc, the routes don't appear to be recognized.

The following is the working code from startup.cs using UseMvc

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/EventLog/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseRequestLocalization();
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(endpoints =>
        {

            endpoints.MapRoute("Grid", "Grid/{action}/{view}",
                new
                {
                    Controller = "Grid",
                    Action = "View"
                });

            endpoints.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Portal}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

And this is the refactored code for UseEndpoints

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/EventLog/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseRequestLocalization();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("Grid", "Grid/{action}/{virtualAction}",
                new
                {
                    Controller = "Grid",
                    Action = "View"
                });

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Portal}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

When I run the application with the UseEndpoints code, I get an error from my custom AuthorizationHandler because there are no values in httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.RouteValues. If I remove the MapControllerRoute code for the Grid route, the default routes work fine with the AuthorizationHandler. Can you have multiple controller route patterns when using UseEndpoints?

Comment: There's no problem to have multiple rote patterns when using UseEndPoints.For most apps, calls to UseAuthentication, UseAuthorization,  must appear between the calls to UseRouting and UseEndpoints to be effective.

Comment: It appears that Authorization is happening before the Endpoint is resolved (which makes sense since you are forced to put UseAuthorization before UseEndpoints), but my Authorization requires access to the RouteValues... Is there any way to configure routing so that the RouteValues are available to the Authorization middleware without using UseMvc to configure routing?

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code in below sample and it works well to get value of `IHttpContextAccessor`:

1.My custom authorization handler

```
public class MinimumAgeRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public int MinimumAge { get; }

    public MinimumAgeRequirement(int minimumAge)
    {
        MinimumAge = minimumAge;
    }
}

public class MinimumAgeHandler : AuthorizationHandler<MinimumAgeRequirement>
{
    IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor = null;

    public MinimumAgeHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
                                                   MinimumAgeRequirement requirement)
    {
        var data = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.RouteValues;
        //...
    }
}
```

2.ConfigureServices:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AtLeast21", policy =>
                policy.Requirements.Add(new MinimumAgeRequirement(21)));
        });
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, MinimumAgeHandler>();

    }
```

3.Controller

```
[Authorize(Policy = "AtLeast21")]
public class GridController : Controller
```